# Multidimensional array assigning in loop stating: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, lvalue

So in a class, I have an array like so:

```
public:
    int playGrid[10][10];//size of the grid, 10x10 or 100 squares
```

And when I do:

```
        for (int i = iX1; i < iX2; i++)
        {
            if (i == iX1)
            {
                playGrid[i][iY1] = 4;
            }
        }
```

This:

```
playGrid[i][iY1] = 4;
```

gives me:

```
expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. This code is inside one of the methods for the class, so it has access to it. I've looked all over the place, but I was unable to find an example where they were using 2D arrays with a simple integer assignment.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: More code was requested, so here we go:

```
void Grid::placeBoat(int iX1, int iY1, int iX2, int iY2) const
{
    if (iX1 != iX2)
    {
        if (iX1 < iX2)
        {
            for (int i = iX1; i < iX2; i++)
            {
                if (i == iX1)
                {       
                    playGrid[i][iY1] = 4;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else if (iY1 != iY2)
    {

    }
}
```

and here is the grid class:

```
class Grid
{
public:
    int playGrid[10][10];//size of the grid, 10x10 or 100 squares
    void drawGrid() const;
    void placeBoat(int, int, int, int) const;
    Grid();
    ~Grid();
};
```

Comment: Not the exact cause of your bug but I think you mean `if (i == iX1)` instead of `if (i = iX1)`

Comment: Need to see more code. The error is not in the lines of code you posted (even if the error message is).

Comment: @john I have added more code as requested.

Comment: @liliscent      Oh. Yep. that was it.... I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Grid::placeBoat(int iX1, int iY1, int iX2, int iY2) const
```

See the `const` at the end of the definition? It means that you are allow calling this method when the instance (`Grid`) is constant.

Since you allow that call, the entire function body is compiled assuming that `this` is of type `const Grid *`.

You are then trying to change the array, which is a member of the (const) Grid, and hence the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in a method that is const you are trying to modify the object. Remove the const

```
class Grid
{
    ...
    void placeBoat(int, int, int, int);
    ...
};

void Grid::placeBoat(int iX1, int iY1, int iX2, int iY2)
{
    ...
}
```